# Multithreading, Read multiple files and write to new Files

Tags: java, multithreading, file

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Test6 implements Runnable {

    private File file;
    private int totalNumberOfFiles = 0;
    private static int nextFile = -1;
    private static ArrayList<String> allFilesArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static ExecutorService executorService = null;

    public Test6(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    private String readFileToString(String fileAddress) {
        FileInputStream stream = null;
        MappedByteBuffer bb = null;
        String stringFromFile = "";
        try {
            stream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileAddress));
            FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
            bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
            /* Instead of using default, pass in a decoder. */
            stringFromFile = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("readFileToString IOException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("readFileToString IOException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return stringFromFile;
    }

    private void toFile(String message, String fileName) {
        try {
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:/Users/Nomi/Desktop/Workspace2/Test6/TestWritten/" + fileName);
            System.out.println("printing to file: ".concat(fileName));
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            out.write(message);
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("toFile() Exception");
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

//  private void listFilesForFolder(final File fileOrFolder) {
//      String temp = "";
//      if (fileOrFolder.isDirectory()) {
//          for (final File fileEntry : fileOrFolder.listFiles()) {
//              if (fileEntry.isFile()) {
//                  temp = fileEntry.getName();
//                  toFile(readFileToString(temp), "Copy".concat(temp));
//              }
//          }
//      }
//      if (fileOrFolder.isFile()) {
//          temp = fileOrFolder.getName();
//          toFile(readFileToString(temp), "Copy".concat(temp));
//      }
//  }

    public void getAllFilesInArrayList(final File fileOrFolder) {
        String temp = "";
        System.out.println("getAllFilesInArrayList fileOrFolder.getAbsolutePath()" + fileOrFolder.getAbsolutePath());
        if (fileOrFolder.isDirectory()) {
            for (final File fileEntry : fileOrFolder.listFiles()) {
                if (fileEntry.isFile()) {
                    temp = fileEntry.getAbsolutePath();
                    allFilesArrayList.add(temp);
                }
            }
        }
        if (fileOrFolder.isFile()) {
            temp = fileOrFolder.getAbsolutePath();
            allFilesArrayList.add(temp);
        }
        totalNumberOfFiles = allFilesArrayList.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < allFilesArrayList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("getAllFilesInArrayList path: " + allFilesArrayList.get(i));
        }
    }

    public synchronized String getNextFile() {
        nextFile++;
        if (nextFile < allFilesArrayList.size()) {
//          File tempFile = new File(allFilesArrayList.get(nextFile));
            return allFilesArrayList.get(nextFile);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        getAllFilesInArrayList(file);
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(allFilesArrayList.size());
        while(nextFile < totalNumberOfFiles)
        {
            String tempGetFile = getNextFile();
            File tempFile = new File(allFilesArrayList.get(nextFile));
            toFile(readFileToString(tempFile.getAbsolutePath()), "Copy".concat(tempFile.getName()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test6 test6 = new Test6(new File("C:/Users/Nomi/Desktop/Workspace2/Test6/Test Files/"));
        Thread thread = new Thread(test6);
        thread.start();
//      executorService.execute(test6);
//      test6.listFilesForFolder(new File("C:/Users/Nomi/Desktop/Workspace2/Test6/"));
    }
}
```

The programs' doing what's expected. It goes into the folder, grabs a file, reads it into a string and then writes the contents to a new file.
I would like to do this multi threaded. If the folder has N number of files, I need N number of threads. Also I would like to use executor framework if possible. I'm thinking that there can be a method along this line:

```
public synchronized void getAllFilesInArrayList() {
        return nextFile;
    }
```

So each new thread could pick the next file.
Thank you for your help.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:589)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:480)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Executors.java:59)
    at Test6.run(Test6.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: So? Make it multithreaded. What's the problem? Seems like you know already what you should do.

Comment: No, I don't, that is why I've posted here.

Comment: You say that you need N number of threads and you say you would like to use the executor framework. If you don't know how to use those things, google them. Your idea of using the synchronized keyword is correct. Go ahead and try some, see what you can do, you might surprise yourself. Then come back if you encounter any problem with your newly found knowledge.

Comment: Okay, thank you. "Your idea of using the synchronized keyword is correct." I wasn't sure about this.

Comment: just remember to change the `nextFile` variable within the synchronized method - I would call the method `getNextFile()` and let it return a File object, and remember that void-methods can't return anything. (which makes your `return nextFile;` a little strange).

Comment: I'm stuck at my run method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your approach to the problem will result in more synchronization and race condition worries than seems necessary.  A simple strategy to keep your threads from racing would be this:

1) Have a dispatcher thread read all the file names in your directory.

2) For each file, have the dispatcher thread spawn a worker thread and hand off the file reference

3) Have the worker thread process the file

4) Make sure you have some sane naming convention for your output file names so that you don't get threads overwriting each other.

As for using an executor, a ThreadPoolExecutor would probably work well. Go take a look at the javadoc:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: I think I like your approach better. Some code would be nice, please. Thank you.

Comment: @NomanArain You have some code here already, Aurand gave you four steps of pseudocode basically. Don't always expect a complete solution. This is StackOverflow and not "Please do my work for me".

Comment: I doubt if we can improve performance here with multiple threads. Multiple threads would cause more frequent disk head movements.
In my case, single thread performance was approximately equal with 10-50 threads. It goes on to degrade if I increase number of threads in the pool.